# Can I use the equality $\phi^2=\phi+1$ without proving it?

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I am looking at the following exercise:

> Show with induction, that the $i^{\rm th}$ Fibonacci number satisfies the equality:
>
> $$F_i=\frac{\phi^i-\hat{\phi}^i}{\sqrt{5}}$$
>   where $\phi$ represents the golden ratio and $\hat{\phi}$ is its conjugate.

It is known that:
$$F_0=0 \\ F_1=1 \\ F_i=F_{i-1}+F_{i-2}, i \geq 2 \\ \phi=\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}, \hat{\phi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

That's what I have tried:

- $$F_0=\frac{\phi^0-\hat{\phi}^0}{ \sqrt{5}}=0 \checkmark$$

$$F_1=\frac{\phi-\hat{\phi}}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}=1 \checkmark$$

- We suppose that the relation stands for $2 \leq i \leq n$:
  $$F_i=\frac{\phi^i-\hat{\phi}^i}{\sqrt{5}}$$
- We will show that the relation stands for $n+1$:

$$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}=\frac{\phi^n-\hat{\phi}^n}{ \sqrt{5}}+\frac{\phi^{n-1}-\hat{\phi}^{n-1}}{ \sqrt{5}}=\frac{\phi^{n-1}(\phi+1)-\hat{\phi}^{n-1}(\hat{\phi}+1)}{\sqrt{5}} (*)$$

Then,using the equality $\phi^2=\phi+1$,I got:

$$(*)=\frac{\phi^{n-1} \phi^2-\hat{\phi}^{n-1} \hat{\phi}^2}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-\hat{\phi}^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Can I just use the equality  $\phi^2=\phi+1$ without a proof, or do I have to prove it?

Comment: It's not too hard to prove, why are you avoiding it?  Just calculate $\phi^2$ and simplify.

Comment: I'd say it's fine to use that equality without proof. If you're supposed to know what the conjugate of $\phi$ is, you  surely know that $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$.

Comment: A ok..If I would like to prove it,would I do it like that?

$$\phi^2=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2=\frac{6+2 \sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{3+ \sqrt{5}}{2}= \phi+1$$

Comment: Actually, it more correct to say that $\phi^2=\phi+1$ is the definition of Golden ration than $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ is.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Nice,thank you!!!

Comment: There is a problem with the induction: you prove the cases $i=0$ and $i=1$ then you check that, for every $i\geqslant2$, the case $i$ implies the case $i+1$. This avoids that the case $i=1$ implies the case $i=2$, hence this cannot prove that the assertion holds for every $i\geqslant0$.

Comment: @Did How can I do it then?

Comment: Write down the induction correctly--and I don't think this should be a problem to make it work.

Comment: @Did I used the strong induction..is it wrong?